# Change textarea rows in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I'm trying to change the UI in one of our web administration interfaces with Tampermonkey but I can't get it to work, probably because they've set the same id for the tr, span AND textarea elements.

```
<tr id=thisspecificid>
    <span id=thisspecificid>
        <div>
            <textarea id=thisspecificid rows=15></textarea>
```

If I run `$("#rule_definition")` I only get the tr element.

Do you have any idea on how to change the textarea to ie 30 rows?

Please note that I do not have any control over the html part at all and I ONLY want to change the rows, nothing else.

Kind regards,
Patrik

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique per document. `$("#rule_definition")`, under the hood, uses `document.getElementById()`, which per definition only delivers one item.

Comment: This HTML markup is so bad in many ways...

Comment: Why not set height using CSS?

Comment: My bad. I did not mean to use the rule definition. It was mean to be $("#thisspecificid")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will find the `textarea` element in the `#thisspecificid`

```
$('#thisspecificid textarea').attr('rows', 20);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/rwmwyhd6/

Answer (score 3):

You can add *type* of control in the selector with id to get specific element you want. You can use attribute selector with type of element as under. In the attribute selector use the `*` as a wild card for elements containing the given string in the id.

```
$("textarea[id*=rule_definition]").attr('rows','30');
```

If you are sure the id will start with `rule_definition` you can use starts with selector using `^` instead of `*`

```
$("textarea[id^=rule_definition]").attr('rows','30');
```

Answer (score 2):

> ***Note:*** All id's must be unique and if not please do

To change the textarea to 30 rows **(assumed :one textarea)**  you can do like

```js
$('textarea').attr("rows","30")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id=thisspecificid rows=15></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use .attr() to change it:

```
$('tr textarea').attr("rows","30");
```

read more about [jquery.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)