# Rails text_area dynamic height according to newlines

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a text area field for messaging module. I want to set the text area row to 1 as default. However, when the text area field has some `\n` (newline), I want to dynamically increase the row.
The code below will set the rows to 1 as the `@direct_message.body` is null in the beginning. However, when I type some texts with newlines, it doesn't work as expected.

```
<%= form.text_area :body, rows: (@direct_message.body || "\n").lines.count, value: @direct_message.body, class: "form-control", placeholder: "", autocomplete: 'off'%>
```

My goal is to let the text_area expand as user's message is longer than 1 line.

I came from a ReactJs background so I am not sure if there is state management in rails view to re-render the text-area dynamically

Comment: It does not work like that in Rails. That text area is rendered on the server. You either do an ajax request to the server to re-render it or use js to manipulate the DOM.  But what's wrong with `rows: X` and show a scrollbar ?

Comment: I am trying to mimic the behavior in the Facebook chat/ Slack message behavior where the height will dynamically scale according to the string.

Comment: Then as I said. Probably with JS is easier.

Comment: Sorry, I may need your help to elaborate on the JS method. Is it to refactor the whole rails view into the ReactJS app or do we inject some javascript code in the Rails view's form?

Comment: I'd go with inject js. Do you have jquery? Bind a `change` event on the input and based on how many newlines you have on the value, set the rows. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190001/change-textarea-rows-in-jquery

Comment: I don't have jQuery. But I can introduce them into my rails app if necessary. I will take a look at it. Thanks a lot

Comment: You don't have to use jquery, use  vanilla if you want.

Comment: On what version of Rails are you on? There's Hotwire and I think that works too. Not sure, I haven't used it.

Comment: I am using Rails of 6.0.3. I will research these directions.